# How to dynamically pass cell values as a parameter for new PowerQuery?

Tags: json, excel, vba, powerquery

I created a connection to REST API using PowerQuery in Excel2016 and it gets me information about companies.

In a certain query table, after the results are loaded, there is a column with ID of the company. Now, i want to be able to click on some id and this could be passed to my new query with this id as a parameter in a header. My connection string looks like this:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://rejestr.io/api/v1/persons/"& Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="ID"]}[Content]{0}[Column1] &"/relations", [Headers=[Authorization="xxxxxxxxx"]]))
<..rest of the code, mainly formatting...>
in
"ColumnChanged"
```

Here im referencing the ID from a certain cell (user provided), but i want to be able to pass in this place a value from just selected cell on ID column and then a new query should be created and loaded onto a new worksheet.

I was thinking about this function to "get" a value cell from that column:

Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

But i cannot figure out how to launch a new power query with that...

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, the idea is to avoid manipulating Power Query code directly via VBA (since you cannot be sure the result will be syntactically valid in M).

However, you genuinely seem to want to create a separate new sheet and query each time the user clicks an ID.

I therefore suggest you ignore my previous answer/approach and try the code below. I can't test the code (since I don't have my own credentials for this rejestr.io API) but I think it should work:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.CountLarge <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target.Parent.Range("ID"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    ' If there is any additional validation required (e.g. if the ID should be numeric,
    ' or should satisfy some condition/criteria) then it should be done here
    ' before proceeding to code below.

    Dim idSelected As String
    idSelected = Target.Value

    Dim targetQuery As WorkbookQuery
    Set targetQuery = GetOrCreateQueryFromId(idSelected)

    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

    Dim targetTable As ListObject
    Set targetTable = targetSheet.ListObjects.Add( _
        SourceType:=0, _
        Source:="OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" & targetQuery.Name & ";Extended Properties=""""", _
        Destination:=targetSheet.Range("$A$1") _
    )

    With targetTable.QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [" & targetQuery.Name & "]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "_" & targetQuery.Name
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub


Private Function GetOrCreateQueryFromId(ByVal someId As String) As WorkbookQuery
    ' Should accept an ID and return the existing WorkbookQuery object.
    ' If no query for the ID exists, this function should create one (and then
    ' return the newly created query).

    Dim targetQuery As WorkbookQuery

    On Error Resume Next
    Set targetQuery = ThisWorkbook.Queries(someId)
    On Error GoTo 0

    Dim queryAlreadyExists As Boolean
    queryAlreadyExists = Not (targetQuery Is Nothing)

    Dim queryFormula As String
    queryFormula = CreateQueryFormulaFromId(someId)

    If queryAlreadyExists Then
        targetQuery.Formula = queryFormula
        Set GetOrCreateQueryFromId = targetQuery
        Exit Function
    End If

    Set GetOrCreateQueryFromId = ThisWorkbook.Queries.Add(Name:=someId, Formula:=queryFormula)
End Function


Private Function CreateQueryFormulaFromId(ByVal someId As String) As String
    ' Given an ID, should return the Power Query code (code only) required to get data for that ID.
    ' This function returns the code itself only. It doesn't create the query object.

    CreateQueryFormulaFromId = _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
        " Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(""https://rejestr.io/api/v1/krs/" & someId & "/relations"", [Headers=[Authorization=""x""]]))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
        " #""Converted to Table"" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
        " #""Expanded Column1"" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#""Converted to Table"", ""Column1"", {""address"", ""business_insert_date"", ""ceo"", ""current_relations_count"", ""data_fetched_at"", ""first_entry_date"", ""historical_relations_count"", ""id"", ""is_opp"", ""is_removed"", ""krs"", ""last_entry_date"", ""last_entry_no"", ""last_state_entry_date"", ""last_state_entry_no"", ""legal_form"", ""name"", ""name_short"", ""nip"", ""regon"", ""type"", ""w_likwidacji"", ""w_upadlosci"", ""w_zawieszeniu"", ""relations"", ""birthday"", ""first_name"", ""krs_person_id"", ""last_name"", ""organizations_count"", ""second_names"", ""sex""}, " & _
            "{""Column1.address"", ""Column1.business_insert_date"", ""Column1.ceo"", ""Column1.current_relations_count"", ""Column1.data_fetched_at"", ""Column1.first_entry_date"", ""Column1.historical_relations_count"", ""Column1.id"", ""Column1.is_opp"", ""Column1.is_removed"", ""Column1.krs"", ""Column1.last_entry_date"", ""Column1.last_entry_no"", ""Column1.last_state_entry_date"", ""Column1.last_state_entry_no"", ""Column1.legal_form"", ""Column1.name"", ""Column1.name_short"", ""Column1.nip"", ""Column1.regon"", ""Column1.type"", ""Column1.w_likwidacji"", ""Column1.w_upadlosci"", ""Column1.w_zawieszeniu"", ""Column1.relations"", ""Column1.birthday"", ""Column1.first_name"", ""Column1.krs_person_id"", ""Column1.last_name"", ""Column1.organizations_count"", ""Column1.second_names"", ""Column1.sex""})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
        "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
        " #""Expanded Column1"""
End Function
```

---

- If that is a genuine API key/credential in your question, then you may want to have the server provider revoke/change it (so that nobody can consume this service API using your credentials).
- There is no error handling implemented and currently the user's input is not validated/sanitised in any way.

Comment: Hi, thank you, please see my follow-up answer in this topic as it is too long to just comment :)

Comment: @Alwexistwo, have rewritten this answer

Comment: this works wonders, thanks! I have one additional question: Is it possible for the newly created sheet to be named not after the value from ID column, but rather the company name which i store in the next column? Can the workbook name get its name from another column?

Comment: You should ask a new question if you need further help. If "company name" is stored to the immediate right of the clicked "ID" and you want to name the worksheet after the "company name", then try something like: `targetSheet.Name = Target.Offset(0,1).Value`. But I believe there are certain characters you cannot include in a worksheet's name. In other words, if the company name contains any invalid characters, you'll get an error when renaming the worksheet.

Comment: Thanks that did it :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I implemented your method. However i encountered 2 problems:

1. When I run the macro when im clicking on defined range and query is added, range is being "shortened" to only the field i just clicked on. So the "idselected" instead of A2:A10 now becames just A2...
2. The query is sucessfully added and parameter is succesfully passed but when i ran the query and the new sheet is added, the error occurs:

"The worksheet data for a table needs to be on the same sheet as the table"

My final VBA code looks like this now:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.CountLarge <> 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Intersect(Target.Parent.Range("Range5"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    With ThisWorkbook
        .Names("Range5").RefersTo = Target



        .Queries.Add Name:="2-1_1", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & " Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(""https://rejestr.io/api/v1/krs/"" & Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=""Range5""]}[Content]{0}[Column1] & ""/relations"", [Headers=[Authorization=""xxxxxxx""]]))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & " #""Converted to Table"" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error), " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & " #""Expanded Column1"" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#""Con" & _
    "verted to Table"", ""Column1"", {""address"", ""business_insert_date"", ""ceo"", ""current_relations_count"", ""data_fetched_at"", ""first_entry_date"", ""historical_relations_count"", ""id"", ""is_opp"", ""is_removed"", ""krs"", ""last_entry_date"", ""last_entry_no"", ""last_state_entry_date"", ""last_state_entry_no"", ""legal_form"", ""name"", ""name_short"", ""nip"", ""regon"", ""type"", ""w_likwidacji"", ""w_upadlo" & _
    "sci"", ""w_zawieszeniu"", ""relations"", ""birthday"", ""first_name"", ""krs_person_id"", ""last_name"", ""organizations_count"", ""second_names"", ""sex""}, {""Column1.address"", ""Column1.business_insert_date"", ""Column1.ceo"", ""Column1.current_relations_count"", ""Column1.data_fetched_at"", ""Column1.first_entry_date"", ""Column1.historical_relations_count"", ""Column1.id"", ""Column1.is_opp"", ""Column1.is_rem" & _
    "oved"", ""Column1.krs"", ""Column1.last_entry_date"", ""Column1.last_entry_no"", ""Column1.last_state_entry_date"", ""Column1.last_state_entry_no"", ""Column1.legal_form"", ""Column1.name"", ""Column1.name_short"", ""Column1.nip"", ""Column1.regon"", ""Column1.type"", ""Column1.w_likwidacji"", ""Column1.w_upadlosci"", ""Column1.w_zawieszeniu"", ""Column1.relations"", ""Column1.birthday"", ""Column1.first_name"", ""Column1.krs_person_id"", ""Column1.last_name"", ""Column1.organizations_count"", ""Column1.second_names"", ""Column1.sex""})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & " #""Expanded Column1"""
       ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=2-1_1;Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$S$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [2-1_1]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "_2_1_1"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    End With
```